# Selenium test case fails for form submitted through ajax

Tags: java, selenium, jsp, selenium-webdriver, ajaxform

I have a simple Login page, which is submitted using AJAX. The form action is "Login".
The servlet mapping for Login is as below:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>devops.ilp1.controllerWithoutDb.UserLoginController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

The UserLoginController class sends the response errors which are displayed on the login page. If errors="", then user is logged in. The user is then redirected to lets say localhost:xxxx/Home
This is working fine manually.
When i run the same using Selenium, after the submit button is clicked, the page navigates to localhost:xxxx/Login and the test case fails.

HTML:

```
<form id="someform" action=Login method="post">
  <input type="text"  class="fadeIn first" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
  <input type="password"  class="fadeIn second" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
  <button class="fadeIn third" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
<script>  
$(document).on("submit", "#someform", function(event) {
    var $form = $(this); 
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(response) {
        if(response){
           $('#someMsg').text(response).show().delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
        }else{
           document.location = "Home"; 
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Selenium testcase:

```
public void loginSuccess() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:6080/ILP_Bookstore");
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
    WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/form/button"));         
    email.sendKeys("govind@yahoo.com");
    pass.sendKeys("govind");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);     
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(button));
    button.click();
    assertTrue(driver.getTitle().equals("HomePage"));
}
```

can someone help ?

Comment: Did you try some wait after button.click() ? before you can do assertion for home page title.

Comment: yes i tried that too, but it didnt work either,

Answer (score 0):

Anyone of these 3 Solutions can work easily:

**Solution 1:**
Use actions class to click
act.click()

**Solution 2:**
Use actions class to move the mouse over the element and click
act.movetoElement(button).click()

**Solution 3:**
You can try to use JavaScriptExecutor

Comment: i tried using action class. it didnt work. Still going to localhost:xxxx/Login

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with firefox webdriver. It didnt seem to load the JQuery script.
I changed to Chrome and it worked.